# Program type already present: org.webrtc.videoengine.ViEAndroidGLES20$ContextFactory

Tags: android, android-multidex

```
Program type already present: org.webrtc.videoengine.ViEAndroidGLES20$ContextFactory
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
org.webrtc.videoengine.ViEAndroidGLES20$ContextFactory, sources=[Unknown 
source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

when i build my android project it happened。
i think because in my project dependencies , two module libs have the same file. because they are in my dependencies's libs ,i don't konw how to do.

**the pictures are the file architecture the two same file**
[image]

[image]

Comment: show your gredle

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the duplicated classes from one of the jars.